# Cannot set user display name in my flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I have been trying to set my user display name upon signup. All of the solution I have found in stackoverflow suggest to use updateProfile(). But it is deprecated, and flutter docs say to use updateDisplayName instead.

I have tried to implement it in this way,

```
 void donorSignUp() async {
    try {
      showLoading();
      await auth
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: email.text.trim(), password: password.text.trim())
          .then((result) {
        String _userId = result.user!.uid;
        _addDonorToFirestore(_userId);
        _clearSignUpControllers();
        result.user?.updateDisplayName(donorModel.value.name);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
      Get.snackbar('Sign Up Failed', 'Try again');
    }
  }
```

However, when I try to show it in my Drawer, calling user?.displayName it doesn't show anything. I have also checked that donorModel.value.name consists a string value, I know its not null. What should I do?

the function donorSignUp() is called inside an elevatedbutton,

```
child: ElevatedButton(
                                      child: Text(
                                        'Register',
                                        style: buttonFontSansita,
                                      ),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        if (authController
                                            .signupFormKey.currentState!
                                            .validate()) {
                                          authController.donorSignUp();
                                        }
                                      },
```

Comment: could you call it over future?

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: donorSignUp() where from you call it, please share  those code where you call donorSignUp()

Comment: I call the function inside an elevatedbutton, I have updated it in the question.

Comment: you can use shared preference when the register is complete you store it and when call your drawer to display name then again call shared preference.

Comment: donorSingup() only gets called when a new user registers into the app. I tried to register a new user in my app and to my surprise, the user display name just changed but the display name is from the immediate previous user's name. This is very weird and I am not getting any clue out of this. Then I signed up another user and the same thing happens again, where the user display name is not the currently signed in user but the previous user's name. @JahidulIslam can you help me on this please?

Comment: do you use shared preference? when you logout you should clear the data.

Comment: No I did not used any shared preference.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to always have the real-time `auth` state is to use the `authStateChanges` listener:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance
  .authStateChanges()
  .listen((User? user) {
    if (user == null) {
      print('User is currently signed out!');
    } else {
      print('User is signed in!');
    }
  });
```

You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage). Ideally you can use a Provider to make the data available through the whole app.